# Styling VTT cues - ::cue(#id) selector does not work

Tags: javascript, video, webvtt, video-subtitles, vtt

I'm trying to style dynamically added VTT cues by trying to target the cue id:

```js
track = video.addTextTrack('captions', 'Captions', 'en');
track.mode = 'showing';

const cue = new VTTCue(0, 10, "Hello world");
cue.id = 'test';
track.addCue(cue);

console.log("ID:", track.cues[0].id)
```

```css
/* This selector does not work */

::cue(#test) {
  color: red;
}


/* The generic selector works */

::cue {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" muted autoplay controls width="400px">
  <source type="video/mp4"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Panorama_of_the_valley_from_Leh_Palace.webm">     </source>
</video>
```

I extremely simplified the example, but it shows the problem.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I tried to follow the W3C specs:
https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#introduction-other-features

> In this example, the cues have an identifier:
>
> WEBVTT
>
> test
>
> 00:00.000 --> 00:02.000 This is a test.
>
> 123 00:00.000 --> 00:02.000 That’s an, an, that’s an L!
>
> crédit de transcription 00:04.000 --> 00:05.000 Transcrit par
> Célestes™ This allows a style sheet to specifically target the cues.
>
> /* style for cue: test */ ::cue(#test) { color: lime; } Due to the
> syntax rules of CSS, some characters need to be escaped with CSS
> character escape sequences. For example, an ID that starts with a
> number 0-9 needs to be escaped. The ID 123 can be represented as "\31
> 23" (31 refers to the Unicode code point for "1"). See Using character
> escapes in markup and CSS for more information on CSS escapes.
>
> /* style for cue: 123 */ ::cue(#\31 23) { color: lime; } /* style for
> cue: crédit de transcription */ ::cue(#crédit\ de\ transcription) {
> color: red; }

I don't know if the id selectors work only with `.vtt` files and not with cues generated via JS. There still are not many info on VTT, since it's still a work in progress technology, I tried different approaches, even using `vtt.js` to parse a VTT string containing inline `::cue` styling, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [class object](https://w3c.github.io/webvtt/#webvtt-class-object) inside the VTT text.

But it requires to modify the text attribute for each VTT object.

Then your css rule will be applied.

```js
track = video.addTextTrack('captions', 'Captions', 'en');
track.mode = 'showing';

// wrap text in <c> txt </c>
const cue = new VTTCue(0, 10, "<c>Hello world</c>");
cue.id = "test";
track.addCue(cue);
```

```css
::cue(#test) {
  color: red;
}
::cue {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" muted autoplay controls width="400px">
  <source type="video/mp4"
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Panorama_of_the_valley_from_Leh_Palace.webm">     </source>
</video>
```

Comment: That's awesome, I ended up with a workaround using the `onenter` callback and changing dinamically the color and bg globally when the cue switches, this way I don't have to add multiple entries to the style. Anyway this seems to fix it, did you read this on some docs or you got there by trial ? They don't seem to mention it on w3c docs, why should the class span be mandatory in order to make the cue id selectable ?

Comment: I linked the class object in the w3c doc. I don't know why they made it mandatory. It was a mix by trial, experience (I wrote a subtitle browser extension some time ago) and reading documentation. Always surprising what works and what doesn't. I don't know what you want to archive, but sometimes css variables are easier to handle, but hard to tell if you don't know the use case.

Comment: In the w3c docs is an explicit an example with your solution, so maybe it is a bug in chrome/firefox ?

Comment: I'm working on a web VTT editor to live edit a video, adding captions, and when done send captions to a be where I hard encode them into the video with ffmpeg. But I need to display them in real time while the user is creating them, style included, so was just playing here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bzikdn?file=src%2FApp.js and got stuck on that issue.